# Query always returning 1 on rows number count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have 'intervalos' that contains a lot of 'entregas' so when I click I wanna count the number of rows, but it always returns '1' as result. What am i doing wrong? Please help.

**Database**[image]

**Entregas Controller**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCarga) {

        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $this->Entregas_Model->get_rows($idCarga);




        $this->load->view('commons/header', $datos);


        $crud->set_language("spanish");
        $crud->set_theme('bootstrap');

        $crud->set_table('entregas');
        $crud->unset_columns(array('accion', 'estado'));

        $crud->display_as('idIntervaloHorario', 'Franja Horaria');
        $crud->display_as('idAcciones', 'Acción');
        $crud->display_as('idEstadoSolicitud', 'Estado Solicitud')->display_as('fechaCita', 'Fecha Cita')
                ->display_as('horaCita', 'Hora Cita')
                ->display_as('numeroEntrega', 'Nº Entrega')
                ->display_as('Origen', 'Orígen')
                ->display_as('cargaPrevista', 'Carga Prevista')
                ->display_as('entregaPrevista', 'Entrega Prevista');


        //Clausula where
        $crud->where('entregas.idIntervaloHorario =', $idCarga);

        $crud->display_as('idCarga', 'Nº Entrega');

        $crud->set_relation('idCarga', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');

        $crud->set_relation('idIntervaloHorario', 'intervalosHorarios', 'intervaloHorario');
        //Relación con la tabla acciones
        $crud->set_relation('idAcciones', 'acciones', 'nombreAccion');
        //Relación con la tabla estado
        $crud->set_relation('idEstadoSolicitud', 'estadosolicitudes', 'nombreEstado');

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
```

**Entregas Model**

```
 public function get_rows($idCarga) {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entregas
        JOIN intervaloshorarios on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = entregas.idCarga
        WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');


        $query = $this->db->count_all_results();


        $num_rows = count($query);
        print_r($num_rows);


        return $num_rows;
    }
```

Comment: When you run a `SELECT COUNT(anything) FROM....` You get only ONE row returned. It is the row that will contain the COUNT

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

```
public function get_rows($idCarga) {

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(idCarga) as count FROM entregas
    JOIN intervaloshorarios on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = entregas.idCarga
    WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ?');    // Safer with bound parameters 


   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);    // prepare
   $stmt->bind_param('s',$idCarga);  // bind the parameter
   $stmt->execute();                 // execute
   $stmt->bind_result($count);
   $stmt->fetch();

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Errrm how are you filling the variable `$count` ??? `$stmt->bind_result($count);` tell mysqli where to put the resulting count value. ___It does not actually go and get it from the result set___

Comment: Steady, I removed the DV. I am not trolling you, just bad answers

Comment: Yet no answer coming from you..?

Comment: It would also have been a good idea to explain a little about the reason i.e.  that a COUNT() with no other columns selected would only EVER return a single row, which is why the OP was always getting a 1

Comment: Yet another answer not required, there are plenty of duplicates

Comment: Plus my comment seemed to answer the question quite adequately

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what should i do with $count, i am very new with php and codeigniter and this is getting me crazy. I filled COUNT(idCarga) ang throw the same result. :(

Comment: Solved I have not auto answer privileges so, this is the solution:
`public function get_rows($idCarga) {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM entregas LEFT JOIN intervaloshorarios on entregas.idCarga = intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario
        WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');

        echo $query->num_rows();


        return $query;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Acording to your query you are alraedy asking for a COUNT

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entregas
        JOIN intervaloshorarios on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = entregas.idCarga
        WHERE entregas.idIntervaloHorario = ' . $idCarga . ';');
```

So basicly, if you run this in phpmyasmin or in your mysql prompt it will give you one result, the 'COUNT' of record that fit your query.

I don't know your interface methods, so i would simply suggest to get the value of this result. it will be your count of rows.

Alternatively, you could simply do a SELECT and then count the number of rows but this would increase your result set and fetching time simply to count something that sql can already count by himself.

Comment: See @clearshot66 answer